# Redirect %23 to #

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a url
domain.xyz/xyz/wtc/id%23name

and I need to create

domain.xyz/xyz/wtc/id#name

```
my rules are here 
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/$2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.*#.*) /$1 [R,NE]
```

last rule convert %23 to # but url look like
domain.xyz/wtc/id#name

Comment: `#` is never part of the URL that the server sees, it's _only_ handled in the browser. There are a couple of existing questions here about that, that I don't have available to mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: Problem only exist at external app (not mine) on IOS and safari, that app show not corectly my URL (on safari, chrome,.edge,ff when Access not VIA app but VIA browser URL is ok), the same app on Android work ok. So i need do something on my own to convert URL from ./xyz/xx/123%23tag to ./xyz/xx/123#tag

Comment: So the problem is that you are losing the `xyz` folder from the resulting URL, or what exactly?